# How to read Visio Shape's text properly

Tags: c#, vba, com-interop, visio

I'm in the middle of trying to transfer VBA code over to C# so that form application I made is standalone. I'm having issues with trying to get the text from a shape that is within a shape(in a group). Here is an example in VBA that works flawless.

```
Dim text as String
text = groupShape.shapes.item("rectangle").text
```

This is returning the correct value.
In C# I am using the microsoft.office.interop.visio.dll reference. I've been able to read in shape names just fine so I know I have the application and document objects working fine. In C# the code above looks like:

```
var text = "";
text = Doc.Shapes.ItemU("groupShape").Shapes.ItemU("rectangle").text
```

This is not returning the correct value. It is saying that it will return "Object" so I believe its not returning a string but an object.

What can I do to solve this in order to return the text? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the actual code I am writing. The vba and the c#

VBA:

```
Dim tempShape As Shape

Set tempShape = ActiveDocument.Pages(pageName).Shapes.Item("MainTable")

txtJobName.value = tempShape.Shapes.Item("textJobName").Text
```

c#

```
IVisio.Shape tempShape = Doc.Pages[Loaded_Page.Name].Shapes.ItemU["MainTable"];

 Txt_JobName.Text = tempShape.Shapes.ItemU["textJobName"].Characters.Text;
```

ANOTHER EDIT:
I've also tried going into the shape data properties by referencing the cell that the text is in and still no luck.

```
Txt_JobName.Text = tempShape.Shapes.ItemU["textJobName"].CellsSRC[8, 0, 0].ResultStr[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, I come to find out the reason the .Text was returning "Obj" is that the shape did not have any text in it. If there is text, it will return it. I got too caught up into the return, "Obj". I wonder why it doesn't return empty text or null if there is no text in the shape. Anyways, all the other answers on this question are very helpful and they lead me to finding my problem.

Comment: That means, your shape has fields. This it my item #3, "Field". Use `shape.Characters.Text` Check Visio docs for what fields are.

Answer (score 2):

First, try using , `.Item` not `.ItemU`, those two are different functions. The default one (one that you are using implicitly in VBA) is `Item`. You may be actually addressing a different shape in c#

Second, `.Text` should be starting with capital T, the code with small t should not compile. Make sure that `.text` in lowercase is not an extension method you imported from somewhere, (unrelated to Visio)

Third caveat - to make sure to get text from shape as you see it in UI, it is better to use `shape.Characters.Text`, because in case shape contains fields, the `shape.Text`will return placeholders ('obj') for those places where the field text should go. But this applies to both VBA and C#

Fourth.. `groupShape` in VBA appears to be a variable name, not shape name. From the code it's not clear what is the name of that group shape. How do you get that one in VBA? May be worth checking.

Comment: I added an update to my question with the actual code. I had all of those check already :/ In c# .item doesn't exist in the library, only .itemu

Comment: @jediderek if there's a `get_Item` method in the interop library, use that.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The .ItemU is the get_item method.

Comment: Yes, and with COM interop being flaky as it is, you should prefer using the getter methods over indexers and properties.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Would you recommend a better library?

Comment: You are right, Item[] is represented as indexer. So exact equivalent of VBA code could be `x.Shapes["groupShape"].Shapes["rectangle"].Text`. Anyways, be careful about NameU: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2006/07/27/name-and-nameu/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with the Visio type library, but this:

```
groupShape.shapes.item("rectangle")
```

Is returning a `Shape` object. Grab that object reference instead of discarding it with another dot. VBA is being "helpful" here, and happily lets you write late-bound calls that will only be resolved at runtime - C# will only be that permissive with the `dynamic` keyword, and you typically don't want to code against `dynamic` - you want to work with strong types:

```
Dim rectangle As Shape
Set rectangle = groupShape.shapes.item("rectangle")

Dim rectangleText As String
rectangleText = rectangle.Text
```

The C# / interop code needs to do the same:

```
var groupShape = (Shape)Doc.Shapes.ItemU("groupShape");
var rectangle = (Shape)groupShape.Shapes.ItemU("rectangle");
var rectangleText = rectangle.Text // assuming Text is defined on the Shape interface
```

In other words, always be aware of the types you're working with; if a member returns an `object` and you need it to be a more specific type, you need to cast as appropriate before you can have compile-time validation of the member call, or cast to `dynamic` if you don't care for compile-time validation and defer them to run-time:

```
var text = (string)((dynamic)groupShape.Shapes.ItemU("rectangle")).Text
```

Notice the cast to `string`; `text` will be a `string`. Forget that cast and your code will have to deal with `dynamic` spreading throughout the execution paths like a cancer and ruining your type safety - and you don't want that.

Comment: What you said made sense but sadly did not work in my favor. I tried creating a 2nd shape object like in your example and tried grabbing the text and still the same result(I also tried a few other ways with the information you gave as well with casting to dynamic/string).

Comment: I don't know what it was but all of a sudden this is working. It wasn't working before, but now it is.

Comment: Could have been a misplaced parenthese.